# Issues centering table with altered fontsize

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, fontsize

I am doing my thesis and want to have all table consistently centered on the page, and \footnotesize text. For some reason one table decides to left justify when I make it footnote size (or any other size):

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Variants in genes with AF $< 0.01$ in Individual II1, Family A.}
    \label{table:BBS_var} 
\begin{footnotesize}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llllrr}
    \hline
    \textbf{Gene} & \textbf{Nucleotide} & \textbf{Amino-acid} & \textbf{Transcript} &  \textbf{ESP} & \textbf{GERP}\\
        &   \textbf{change} & \textbf{change} & \textbf{ID} & \textbf{AF} &\textbf{++} \\
    \hline
    \textit{Lorem}  & . & . & Lorem  & 0.00186 & 5.4  \\
    \textit{Lorem} & . & . & Lorem            & .        & 2.25 \\
    \textit{Lorem}  & .  & . & Lorem          & .        & 5.67 \\
    \textit{Lorem}  & .  & . & Lorem             & 0.000116 & 5.67 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{table}
```

If I remove the \footnotsize lines then it centres the table fine, but is the wrong size text obviously.

I can also use \begin{centre} within the table environment, but then this adds a large gap between the caption and table, which is also undesired.

I have another almost identical table (aside from the data) which reduces size without issue. I have tried copying this table and repopulating it for the data for this table, but then the issue magically manifests again.

Any ideas? It's starting to make me feel I'm going a little bit insane now....

PS. Using Pdflatex 2013.9.11, preamble is:

```
%% General layout
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=2cm,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UTF8 encoding solves issuse in references with obscure characters
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % adds subscript command
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%Figure layout
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=12pt,font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}

%PDF bookmarks
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 pt}
```

Comment: try putting the `\centering` outside the `footnotesize` environment.

Comment: Cheers, his has fixed the problem for this table.

I'm very confused as to why this wasn't a problem for the other table though, oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands that set paragraph parameters, `\centering`, `\footnotesize`, `\raggedright`, etc. have to be in scope at the *end* of the paragraph as the final values are used to set the paragraph. So you either need to not have a group (which is made by using the environment form of `\footnotesize` or you need to include a blank line *before* the end of the environment. In this example the problem was mostly apparent in `\centering` which went out of scope before the paragraph ended, but also the `footnotesize` didn't really work either as the baselineskip reverted to normalsize. There was only one "line" (the tabular) in this paragraph so it didn't matter so much, but in general font size changes need the paragraph break.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `footnotesize` environment. Just write

```
\centering\footnotesize
```

instead. By the way, the `subfigure`package is obsolete and no more maintained. Use  `subfig` or `subcaption` (part of the `caption`package) or `floatrow`, which has a  `subfloatrow` environment.

Result, compiled with the `showframe` option of geometry:

[image]

Comment: This did the trick too.

And I'll look into the other non deprecated packages, thanks for the heads-up.